# Add Button in Relative Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button, layout-inflater

I want to add some button in a Sliding Drawer's content, its content is a Relative Layout. 
The button will be defined in Java code and the Relative Layout is already defined in xml layout. So, let's say i want to add 4 buttons:

```
for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
     Button btn = new Button(this);
     btn.setId(i);
     btn.setText("some_text");
}
```

Then i initialize the Relative Layout:

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.slidingDrawerContent);
```

Now how do i add all of the Button into the Relative Layout? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.slidingDrawerContent);
for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
     Button btn = new Button(this);
     btn.setId(i);
     btn.setText("some_text");
    layout.add(btn); 
}
```

or

a bit advance

```
 RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.slidingDrawerContent);
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );


    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
         Button btn = new Button(this);
         btn.setId(i);
         btn.setText("some_text");

        // lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, <Id>);

         layout.addView(tv2, lp); 
    }
```

Comment: there is a dot missing in the for-loop between layout and add(btn) for those who just copy/paste the solution ;)

Comment: You did not declare tv2 or am i missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

simply do this:

```
layout.addView(btn);
```